# Casting Issue in MATLAB C/MEX

Tags: c, matlab, casting, mex

I'm passing an array of complex doubles from matlab into a cmex file in order to perform a sequential operation on them. When I cast the number retrieved from the mxArray to a double, it seems to be misinterpreting the code.

```
double *Xr, *Xi;
Xr = mxGetPr(IN_0);
Xi = mxGetPi(IN_0);
for(i = 1; i < 20; i++){
    printf("%d: %d+i%d\n",i,*Xr,*Xi);
    Xr++;Xi++;
}
```

This yields very high values such as the one that follows

```
15: -803610318+i-1940584014
16: 1832649449+i300289408
17: -1676226884+i1653608050
18: -88066604+i-2135293182
```

I noticed if I replace the `%d` with a `%f` so that printf reads it as a floating point number, the output matches my matlab variable that is being passed in

```
   printf("%d: %f+i%f\n",i,*Xr,*Xi);
```

Yields

```
15: -0.000538+i0.000221
16: -0.000602+i0.000596
17: 0.000550+i-0.000179
18: -0.000371+i-0.001420
```

This is correct.

However, if I try to change the type of my pointer to float I get the incorrect answer again.

```
float *Xr, *Xi;
Xr = mxGetPr(IN_0);
Xi = mxGetPi(IN_0);
for(i = 1; i < 20; i++){
    printf("%d: %f+i%f\n",i,*Xr,*Xi);
    Xr++;Xi++;
}
```

Yields

```
15: 4596027085627908600000000000000.000000+i-0.000000
16: -0.392485+i0.362957
17: -82893360.000000+i0.000000
18: 0.412054+i-0.383178
```

To me it looks as if the data is coming through encoded in a floating point representation, but is seen by the compiler as a double, causing it to be casted to float when assigned to a float type. Other than that I do not know how to solve this problem and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `%d` specifier with anything other than an `int` argument (or something that promotes to `int`) is undefined behavior.

For your third example, casting pointers does not convert the underlying data.  You are assigning a pointer to `double` to a pointer to `float`, and dereferencing that is undefined behavior.

The data coming from Matlab is an array of `double`s and must be treated that way.  If you need to, you can convert the elements one at a time to another type.

Comment: My understanding of C is definitely much shakier than I thought, thank you.